# Neural Network From Scratch - Forward propagation error

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, neural-network

I wanna implement the backward propagation concept in python with the next code

```
class MLP(object):
   def __init__(self, num_inputs=3, hidden_layers=[3, 3], num_outputs=2):
      self.num_inputs = num_inputs
      self.hidden_layers = hidden_layers
      self.num_outputs = num_outputs

        
      layers = [num_inputs] + hidden_layers + [num_outputs]

      weights = []
      bias = []
      for i in range(len(layers) - 1):
         w = np.random.rand(layers[i], layers[i + 1])
         b=np.random.randn(layers[i+1]).reshape(1, layers[i+1])  
         weights.append(w)
         bias.append(b)
      self.weights = weights
      self.bias = bias

      activations = []
      for i in range(len(layers)):
         a = np.zeros(layers[i])
         activations.append(a)
      self.activations = activations

   def forward_propagate(self, inputs):
     activations = inputs
     
     self.activations[0] = activations
     for i, w in enumerate(self.weights):
       for j, b in enumerate(self.bias):
         net_inputs = self._sigmoid((np.dot(activations, w)+b))
         self.activations[i + 1] = net_inputs
     return activations

   def train(self, inputs, targets, epochs, learning_rate):
     for i in range(epochs):
       sum_errors = 0
       for j, input in enumerate(inputs):
         target = targets[j]
         output = self.forward_propagate(input)

   def _sigmoid(self, x):
     y = 1.0 / (1 + np.exp(-x))
     return y
```

So I created the next dummy data in order to verify everything is correct

```
items = np.array([[random()/2 for _ in range(2)] for _ in range(1000)])
targets = np.array([[i[0] + i[1]] for i in items])
    
mlp = MLP(2, [5], 1)
    
mlp.train(items, targets, 2, 0.1)
```

but when I run the code I have the next error

```
ValueError: shapes (2,) and (5,1) not aligned: 2 (dim 0) != 5 (dim 0)
```

I understand the error, but how to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a couple of major problems with `forward_propagate`:

1. change `net_inputs` to `activations` - otherwise you always compute and return the activations from the first layer
2. remove `for j, b in enumerate(self.bias):` - biases from other layers have no business here
3. use `matmul` instead of `dot`

so, something like

```py
for i, w in enumerate(self.weights):
  activations = self._sigmoid((np.matmul(activations, w)+self.bias[i]))
  self.activations[i + 1] = activations
return activations
```

Also, be careful to note that this method receives 1D array, which converts to a matrix after the first `matmul`. Matrixes are stored in `self.activations` and a matrix is returned from the method.
This might or might not be what you want.